# Only first datepicker is shown in bootstrap modal view

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, bootstrap-modal, unify

I have four datepicker inputs in my form which is in bootstrap modal view from unify template http://htmlstream.com/preview/unify-v1.7/shortcode_form_advanced.html

Only first input has datepicker and the rest is not working. The link to the site is here

http://www.ztraty.8u.cz/pridat-novy-nalez.php

Comment: `TypeError: $(...).summernote is not a function`  and `ReferenceError: ProgressBar is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

I have just gone through your `custom.js`, you are using id for calling `datepicker` as below.

```
$('#date').datepicker();
```

Use the class name instead to call all the `datepickers`.

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
```

Answer (score 0):

call the

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
```

after .modal